# C#, XML: move second namespace to root element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I am trying to create an XML document, using the System.XML.XmlDocument Class.

I have two namespaces in my document.

What my C# code looks like:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.InsertBefore(xDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8","yes"),xDoc.DocumentElement);
XmlElement root = xDoc.CreateElement('ROOT','http://example.org/ns1');
xDoc.AppendChild(root);
XmlElement child1 = xDoc.CreateElement('CHILD1','http://example.org/ns1');
root.AppendChild(child1);
XmlElement child2 = xDoc.CreateElement('ns2:CHILD2','http://example.com/ns2');
root.AppendChild(child2);
XmlElement child3 = xDoc.CreateElement('ns2:CHILD3','http://example.com/ns2');
root.AppendChild(child3);
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<ROOT xmlns="http://example.org/ns1" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2">
    <CHILD1/>
    <ns2:CHILD2/>
    <ns2:CHILD3/>
</ROOT>
```

Actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<ROOT xmlns="http://example.org/ns1">
    <CHILD1/>
    <ns2:CHILD2 xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2"/>
    <ns2:CHILD3 xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2"/>
</ROOT>
```

Because elements of the second namespace occur multiple times in my document, I don't want this repetitive declaration of the second namespace, but instead have it only once in the root element.

How can I achieve that?

Using LINQ2XML is not an option for me.

Comment: Out of interest, *why* can you not use LINQ to XML? It may affect other aspects of answers - for example, if for some odd reason you're restricted to .NET 2.0.

Comment: How about `root.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns2", "http://example.com/ns2");`? Not sure if that's gonna make it exactly the way you want. Consider having a look at various methods in the XmlElement class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlElement_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @JonSkeet: long story short, I am not directly programming in C#, only using the libraries in another language, where I can't use .NET-Arrays, and therefor not use the structure of LINQ. I use .NET 4.0

Comment: @MariusUt: That was the first thing I've tried, but that always removed the "ns2:" in front of the elements. However, if I combine this with the explicit namespace declaration for each element, it works. Thank you :)

Comment: I think you may have understood what LINQ to XML is - it's *just* an XML API which happens to work well with LINQ... not that LINQ requires arrays anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add all of your desired namespaces as attributes to root element, like

```
root.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns2", "http://example.com/ns2");
```

Adding this single line at the end will produce almost exactly your desired output (the only difference is order of `xmlns` attributes, but I think it doesn't matter in your case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ROOT xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2" xmlns="http://example.org/ns1">
    <CHILD1 />
    <ns2:CHILD2 />
    <ns2:CHILD3 />
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was actually the first thing I've tried, but at that time I didn't declare the namespace explicitly for each element, so it didn't work.
The combination of both attempts is it :)